# Why this can't work - live update using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing my code like this:

```
function updates_cb()
{
    in a while loop to call append_message
}

function append_message(message)
{
    append the html of message into the page
    now I am using selector to add callback to newly added element
    $(jmsg).hover(function(){console.log("hover");})
}
```

The problem is very weird, only the last element that added has .hover() callback setup, others don't have hover event handler setup.

Am I doing wrong? I can't manipulate the newly added element using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're stumbling across the most common Javascript problem ever:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    setTimeout(function () { alert(x); }, 1000);
}
```

This alerts '10' ten times. This is because the variable `x` in `alert(x)` is a live reference, not a copy, so it'll alert whatever `x` is at the time it needs to alert, not what `x` was when the timeout was set. This works because of [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). Use another anonymous function, which introduces a new variable scope, and another closure to solve this:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    setTimeout((function (y) {
        return function () { alert(y); }
    })(x), 1000);
}
```

Since your code doesn't really show anything I could base a real answer on, I hope this helps you understand the concept.